# Submit form with file upload

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.3

I would like to implement form with file upload. I tried this.

```
<f:websocket channel="uploadProgress" scope="view" onmessage="updateProgressBar" />
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="new_table">
        ..................
    </h:panelGrid>

    <div class="row">
        <h:messages id="uploadMsgId" globalOnly="true" showDetail="false" showSummary="true"/>

        <h:inputFile id="fileToUpload" required="true" requiredMessage="No file selected ..." value="#{newProcedure.file}"/>
        <h:message showDetail="false" showSummary="true" for="fileToUpload"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{newProcedure.upload()}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" onevent="progressBar" render="@form"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <div>
            <div id="progressBarId" width="250px;" height="23"/>
        </div>
    </div>            
    <h:commandButton styleClass="button" value="Create Procedure" action="#{newProcedure.addNewProcedure(1)}">
        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>&nbsp;
</h:form>
```

I can upload file when I press the internal h:commandButton but when I press the second button to submit the form with the attached file nothing happens.
Any idea why it;s not working? Also if there is no selected file how I can submit the form without the attached file? I need to implement some check?